# Angular. More specifically, if the condition in the array

Tags: angularjs

I have this code:

```
<div style="cursor:pointer;padding-top:3px;padding-left{{arrow_pos[road.id+'_'+scale.year+'_'+scale.week]}}px"  >
    <div class="arrow_title">{{arrow_title[road.id+'_'+scale.year+'_'+scale.week]}}</div>
    <div class="{{arrow[road.id+'_'+scale.year+'_'+scale.week]}}"></div>
</div>
```

How do `ng-if` so that this piece of code generated as
`Arrow [road.id + '_' + scale.year + '_' + scale.week]` is not empty.

I tried this:

```
<div ng-if="arrow_title[road.id+'_'+scale.year+'_'+scale.week] !=''">
    same code for the two inner divs
</ div>
```

> AngularJS v1.0.7

but it does not work.
How to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression:

```
arrow_title[road.id+'_'+scale.year+'_'+scale.week] !=''
```

Looks like you are accessing a property dynamically on the `arrow_title` object.

If this is correct, the result will, most likely, not be `''` (unless the property value is a string).  The result will either be the property value or `undefined`.

As @musically_ut describes, `ng-if` is not available in 1.0.7, but you could use `ng-show` with this expression:

```
<div ng-show="arrow_title[road.id+'_'+scale.year+'_'+scale.week]">
same code
</ div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`ng-if` is only available from Angular 1.2 onwards.

Otherwise, the syntax looks correct.

There are a couple of work workaround for Angular 1.0.7:

1. Using `ng-show/ng-hide` with the same condition
2. Using `ng-switch`:

   ```html
   <div ng-switch="arrow_title[road.id+'_'+scale.year+'_'+scale.week] !=''">
      <div ng-switch-when="true">
            <!-- your code -->
      </div>
    </div>
   ```